# Does linux have Blackbox like mechanism when system crashed in embeded linux?

Tags: linux, kernel

In embeded linux, some times after the system crashes, we hope there is a blackbox (will record the key info before the system restart)
, in linux, is there have such kind of mechanism to record the key data before restart, for example,which process crashed,
what's the memory usage? CPU load? kernel log and app log, core dump file and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Look for the kexec-tools and the kdump-kernel.